# Install xlsxwriter in canopy Python

Tags: python, canopy, xlsxwriter

How can I install xlsxwriter in Canopy Express？
I downloaded the source file from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter#downloads
and tried to install the package like this [Installing a package to Canopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533094/installing-a-package-to-canopy)
but it doesn't work..
Where should I put xlsxwriter package and the setup file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, to install a python package, ***you*** don't explicitly put the package anywhere. You just run the installer, and it downloads the files to a temporary directory and then copies them in the appropriate location (and does other compilation and configuration as needed). But the key is to run the installer from the Python where you want to install the packages.

Concretely in your case, assuming that you are on Windows, simply open a Canopy Command Prompt Window (you can do this from the Canopy Tools menu or from the Windows Start Menu), and type:

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

That's all.

The SO answer that you link to is somewhat misleading. For more context and details, see https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line